# How to add a formatting code rule in VSTS?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, code-formatting, azure-pipelines-build-task

In our team, there are developers using different code formatting. On each code review, we have the same problem again and again, we loose a lot of time remind him to do it in the correct way.
Is there a way to add in VSTS a rule to block the build if the default code formatting is not respected.

Example:

```
//NOT VALID
var user = _userRepository.GetAll()
                         .Where(u => u.Country == "Canada")
                         .ToList(); 
//VALID
var user = _userRepository.GetAll()
   .Where(u => u.Country == "Canada")
   .ToList();
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Add static analysis to your PR builds. Or add something like StyleCop / ReSharper analysis. There are tons of tools to analyze code and display warnings or errors based on rule violations.

Comment: Thanks I will take a look on it.

Answer (score 0):

We are using StyleCop: https://github.com/StyleCop/StyleCop

It is a great tool to enforce a set of style and consistency rules. We added it to the `.csproj` file, so it runs on the developer machines as well to give developers instant feedback, and also as part of our Azure DevOps build pipeline together with the C# compiler.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look on it soon :)